# vba legacy function to return row count returns 1 instead

Tags: vba, rows, areas

I'm working with some legacy code I'd like to build on and I can't seem to figure out the following: Why does the function `AantalZichtbareRows` return 1? Where It says `For Each row In rng.Rows` the row count is 1500 something (and so is the actual excel I'm working with).

I'm specifically puzzeled by `n = r.Areas.Count`. This is where the 1 originates.

```
Sub motivatieFormOpmaken()

Public iLaatsteKolom As Integer
Public iLaatsteRij As Integer
Public iKolomnrCorpID As Integer
Public iKolomnrNaam As Integer
Public iKolomnrHuidigeFunctie As Integer

Const StBestand = "Stambestand.xlsm"
Const motivatie = "Template motivatieformulier opstapregeling.xlsx"

    Dim wbMotivTemp As Workbook
    Dim wsMotiv As Worksheet
    Dim PathOnly, mot, FileOnly As String
    Dim StrPadSourcenaam As String

    Set wbMotivTemp = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsMotiv = ActiveSheet

    StrHoofdDocument = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    StrPadHoofdDocument = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    StrPadSourcenaam = StrPadHoofdDocument & "\" & c_SourceDump

    If Not FileThere(StrPadSourcenaam) Then
       MsgBox "Document " & StrPadSourcenaam & " is niet gevonden."
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Workbooks.Open FileName:=StrPadSourcenaam
    Application.Run "Stambestand.xlsm!unhiderowsandcolumns"
    Worksheets("stambestand").Activate

    iLaatsteKolom = Worksheets("stambestand").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    iLaatsteRij = Worksheets("stambestand").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).row

    VulKolomNr
    If KolomControle = False Then Exit Sub

    Aantalregels = AantalZichtbareRows
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim row As Range
        Dim StrFileName As String
        'If Aantalregels > 1 Then
         Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
         For Each row In rng.Rows
              iRijnummer = row.row
              If iRijnummer > 1 Then
                 wsMotiv.Range("motiv_cid") = Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrCorpID).Text
                 wsMotiv.Range("motiv_naam") = Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrNaam).Text
                 wsMotiv.Range("motiv_ldg") = Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrHuidigeLeidingGevende).Text

                 n = naamOpmaken
                 wbMotivTemp.Activate
                 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=StrPadHoofdDocument & "\Docs\" & n & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
              End If
         Next row

End Sub

Function naamOpmaken() As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    iRijnummer = rng.row
        If iRijnummer > 1 Then
            naam = Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrNaam).Text
            ldg = Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrHuidigeLeidingGevende).Text
            cid = Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrCorpID).Text

            Dim Position As Long, Length As Long
            Dim n As String
            Position = InStrRev(naam, " ")
            Length = Len(naam)
            n = Right(naam, Length - Position)
        End If
    naamOpmaken = n + "-" + ldg + "-" + cid
End Function

Public Function AantalZichtbareRows() As Integer
    Dim rwCt As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Dim n As Long
    Dim I As Long
        Set r = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        n = r.Areas.Count
            For I = 1 To n
              rwCt = rwCt + r.Areas(I).Rows.Count
            Next I
        AantalZichtbareRows = rwCt
End Function
```

Comment: Rng.rows of a disjointed range only retyurns the count of the first area.  You will need to iterate the areas and the rows in each area.

Comment: So tempting to say - your first block of code isn't within a sub, you have an `IF` statement without an `End If` and, well, [MCVE].  Emphasis on _complete_.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook True, thought that the lead-up wasn't that interesting and it works. Concerning the If, I did run into that, just need to get the row count to iterate first and then I can start on that. Thanks anyway, all help is appreciated.

Comment: @ScottCraner: But doesn't it iterate in the `for I = 1 To n` and `next I` bit?

Comment: I was trying to get at that I copied the code, pressed the _compile_ button and it didn't compile so I didn't bother looking further.  Whereas if the code compiled then it would be easier to find the problem - such as the function returning an Integer when it's dealing with row numbers that can exceed the total that the Integer type can handle.

Comment: submitted all code (edit : forgot 2 public declarations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range.areas specifies the number of selection areas. [Range.Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/range-areas-property-excel?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144081)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue)

I tested your code and it works as expected. You can have a single selection area containing 1500 rows. Example: "A1:A1500" Or you can have a selection containing 2 areas with three rows each for a total of 6 rows. Example: "A1:A3" and "C4:C6".

This code might help you understand how the method returns information about the selected cells.

```
Public Function AantalZichtbareRows() As Integer
    Dim rwCt As Long
    Dim rwCt2 As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Dim n As Long
    Dim I As Long

    Set r = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    n = r.Areas.Count
    For I = 1 To n
      rwCt = rwCt + r.Areas(I).Rows.Count
    Next I

    Set r = Selection
    n = r.Areas.Count
    For I = 1 To n
      rwCt2 = rwCt2 + r.Areas(I).Rows.Count
    Next I

    Debug.Print n & " areas selected."
    Debug.Print rwCt2 & " rows selected."
    Debug.Print rwCt & " visible rows selected."
    Debug.Print (rwCt2 - rwCt) & " hidden rows selected."

    AantalZichtbareRows = rwCt
End Function
```

Comment: `r` is 18 million-ish because of the `xlCellTypeVisible` and that's 1 area. Then this line `rwCt = rwCt + r.Areas(I).Rows.Count` counts all the rows in the area, correct? This returns one as well, so the function does too.

Comment: The function counts the total selected rows from all selection areas. If the function returns 1 it's because only one row/cell is selected.

Comment: The xcCellTypeVisible specifies to only consider visible cells in the selection. So if cells in hidden rows are selected they would not be included in the count.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I have to look at another project within the legacy to see why it makes a selection of 1 row and how it handles the rows in the sheet. I'll upate tomorrow. Getting a bit closer piece by piece though. Thanks!

Comment: I would just do something like: count all rows, start at 2 -> do stuff -> row ++ (in vba) and so forth. Different choices were made though.

Comment: Haven't got the time and/or skill to figure it out. Just gonna use my above mentioned solution of counting all the rows I need and then increment after taking action on it. Thanks again for your input though.